# Auto-incrementing field that isn't a primary key

Tags: php, mysql, idiorm

In my MySQl table I have two fields, `id` and `order`. `id` is an auto-incrementing primary key and I want `order`'s initial value to match this, but to also be editable, not a key and with no uniqueness constraints. How can my database insert method achieve this? Is it possible to do so without requerying to find the last inserted id?

I'm using paris/idiorm so a solution making use of their features would be handy, although plain SQL and php is fine too.

Comment: Sounds like a problematic design to me.

Comment: Essencially it's keeping unneeded redundant information that can become a pitfall because it creates a dependency and threatens your database integrity.

Comment: If you need the id of a certain order, you can always concatenate it but store it only in one single place.

Comment: @markus ah, `order` actually refers to the order the items are displayed in, and the default is to show the item last added in the last position, so `order` should equal `id` in order to achieve this. But it's possible for an item to be moved up the display, and `order` changes to reflect this. So it's not duplicating data, just setting an initial value which depends on the id.

Comment: For that you don't need to duplicate the id either. Just sort by (id ASC, order ASC). Or vice versa if order has precedence.

Comment: But order will only initially be the same as id. The point is atht order can be changed to any number. I might, for instance, want to change order to be -1 so that an item always appears at the top. The id will never change, but order might.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL (since version 5.0.2) you can create trigger.

Try this on non-production database:

```
create trigger default_order_value AFTER INSERT ON orders
     UPDATE order SET order = id WHERE id = new.id;
```

It may not work in that way as you wish, but you can edit it. This is another trigger example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER default_order
    BEFORE UPDATE ON orders
    REFERENCING NEW ROW AS n
    n.order = n.id;
```

Comment: Thsi looks ideal. I need to upgrade MySQL first though... luckily it's juust on my local dev machine at present

Comment: I think you definitely have the right idea, but despite playing aroudn a lot with eth syntax I can't get it to work. So far I have CREATE TRIGGER `default_order_value` 
AFTER INSERT ON `clusters` 
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
    UPDATE `clusters` SET `order` =[NEW.id WHERE id = NEW.id; 
END

Comment: See here for how I got it working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353042/can-i-update-the-just-added-row-using-mysql-triggers

Comment: That were triggers from Mysql help. Check your version. Older Mysql versions dont support triggers.

Comment: I'm afraid I had to unanswer this as it turns out an AFTER  trigger can't manipulate the row that just triggered it